# Theorem environment number beneath figure if figure inside environment

Tags: floats, amsthm

I'm trying to set up my theorem environments so that when you have a figure the number for the theorem/example etc. should go above the figure itself. For example:

**Example 1.1**

*tikzpicture*

Currently it is producing

*tikzpicture*

**Example 1.1**

Minimum working example (I've included all the packages I'm using elsewhere on the off chance something there is affecting it):

```
\documentclass[11pt, A4]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows}
\makeatother


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}


\begin{document}
\begin{example}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 1) -- (0, 3);
        \draw (0, 2) -- (1, 2);
        \draw (0, 3) -- (3, 3);
        \draw (1, 1) -- (1, 3);
        \draw (3, 3) -- (3, 2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I've tried setting the position of the figure by making it say
`\begin{figure}[htb]` or just those individually, but the only one that does anything in that respect is `\begin{figure}[b]` and that (rather obviously) moves the figure at the bottom of the page, which isn't feasible for all of the figures across the whole project.

Suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This has little to do with your `theorem` definitions. A float floats. If you do not want a figure to float you should not use the `\begin{figure} \end{figure}` construction.

Try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\begin{example}
\mbox{}

\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 1) -- (0, 3);
        \draw (0, 2) -- (1, 2);
        \draw (0, 3) -- (3, 3);
        \draw (1, 1) -- (1, 3);
        \draw (3, 3) -- (3, 2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{caption of tikz}
\end{center}

Here comes the text of the example.
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

to obtain

[image]

Comment: And quite likely the caption isn't needed.